# Rails Model doesn't save data with polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

I have a model job and a model user, the both can choose contracts types (that's why i use polymorphic).

I created a model contract for each contracts and i create an attached_contract model too.

**Job model**

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contracts, through: :attached_contracts
  has_many :attached_contracts, as: :contractable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attached_contracts, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**AttachedContract model**

```
class AttachedContract < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contract
  belongs_to :contractable, polymorphic: true
  validates :contract, uniqueness: { scope: [:contractable_type,:contractable_id] }
end
```

**Contract model**

```
class Contract < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true, allow_blank: false
  has_many :attached_contracts
end
```

**Jobs_controller**

```
  def new
    @job = Job.new
    @job.attached_contracts.build
  end
  def create
    @job = current_company.jobs.build(set_params)
    if @job.save
      redirect_to job_path(@job)
    end
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
  def set_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:title, :description, :address, attached_contracts_attributes: [:id, :contract_id, :_destroy]
  end
```

**In my view :**

```
<%= simple_form_for([:company, @job]) do |f| %>
  <div class="nested-fields">
    <%= f.association :contracts, as: :check_boxes  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I submit my form my model AttachedContract still empty, and the data are lost.

I try tu put a "raise" in my controller after @job = current_company.jobs.build(set_params)
and I have a empty array if I call @job.attached_contracts 
I don't understand beause in the "Request parameters" (rails debug console) I have the values : "contract_ids"=>["", "1", "3"]

Any idea ? May be the problem is in the polymorphic implantation ?

Comment: In your rails debug console, do you see an unpermitted parameters notification?

Comment: @jvillian no I have nothing like that !

Comment: Ok. Sorry. That was my only guess.

Comment: I think the request parameters should be:

    `{
        attached_contracts_attributes: [
          {contract_id: 1},
          {contract_id: 2}
        ]
    }`

Comment: @reub I just tried it, but unfortunately always a empty array

Comment: Do you have `contractable_type` and `contractable_id` columns in your attached contract schema? Without those ActiveRecord won't be able to fetch polymorphic associations. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: Yes, but i had to create a name for the column ""contrable_type" because the generic name was up to 63 characters, may be is that ? 

  create_table "attached_contracts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "contract_id"
    t.integer  "contractable_id"
    t.string   "contractable_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
    t.index ["contract_id"], name: "index_attached_contracts_on_contract_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["contractable_type", "contractable_id"], name: "contrable_type", using: :btree
  end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I changed the requested parameters by "contract_ids: [ ]" and that's work perfectly !